# Saving messages from telegram group with python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

my personal telegram is in a groupchat and I would like to save the telegram messages and run some code depending on what the text says, but the problem I am having is saving the messages, is it possible to do so? And I am welcome to work arounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with creating a bot using Telegram's @BotFather, you will receive a TOKEN which you will use later.
Then change it's settings so that he will be able to see group messages.

Next you will have to create a web server using Heroku or any other cloud platform in order for your code to run at all times.

configure your bot webhook using Telegram's API and Telebot library to apply the URL destination like this:
This Should run once and looks something like this:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.Telebot(<YOUR_BOT_TOKEN>)
bot.setwebhook(<WEB_SERVER_URL>)
```

After that, any update the bot gets, will be sent as a POST request to this URL containg JSON structure.

later you will have to write your python code and upload it to the web server.
I recommend watching this video to learn about API on Heroku:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5TKQF7WJzc

And reading relevant subjects at Telegram bot's API manual:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api